# How to cp a file only if it isn't already the same?

Tags: npm, terminal, cp

I have a build step in my static site generator that copies things like the favicon, and manifest, but it seems wasteful, since these files rarely change.

How can I change that build step so that it only does the `cp` if the files differ?

My npm script currently: `"build-robots": "cp robots.txt _build/robots.txt",`

Also, it would be great to do the same for directories of files. Like the `/scripts` directory which is full of js files and folders of js files (one for polyfills for example).

Using `cp -ru folder/ _build/` works but it doesn't copy over deletes or renames. Any way to copy deletes and renames?

Comment: There is a `-u` option for GNU `cp` that makes it overwrite only files with older timestamps.

Comment: Nice! Just found that. Any chance there's a way to do this for directories and all their contents?